# How to Populate on Sub Document's Reference (Mongoose)

Tags: node.js, mongoose

How to populate ref document in Sub Document, this my schema:

```
var person = mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: [String], index: true },
    career: [{
        position: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Orgchart' }
    }]
};

var orgchart = mongoose.Schema({
        name: { type: [String], index: true },
};
```

I tried with this part:

```
person.find({ _id: "12345" }).populate('orgchart').exec(function(err, data){
  res.send(data);
});
```

I got error `Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`  when i call on jade template with

```
item.career._orgchart.name
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the dot-notation pathname of the field to populate to the `populate` call:

```
person.find({ _id: "12345" }).populate('career.position').exec(function(err, data){
  res.send(data);
});
```

Not sure why you're trying to access this using `_orgchart` from Jade as it's the same `position` field within an element of the `career` array that will be populated with the referenced `orgchart` doc.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Mr JohnnyHK

I use:

```
person.findOne({ _id: req.params.person }).populate('career.position career.grade').exec(function(err, data){
  res.send(data);
});
```

I used `item.position.name` in loop data on jade template

Thanks